# workaround bug of LoadLibraryEx(..., LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR) loading wrong dll

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, ntdll

The situation is following.
These dlls are loaded in a process:

```
c:\abc\foo.dll
c:\abc\bar.dll
c:\zxc\foo.dll
```

And the process is located in `c:\abc\`.
I'm loading `c:\zxc\bar.dll`. It implicitly links to `foo.dll`. And it should link to `c:\zxc\foo.dll`, which is in same folder.
I load it with

```
LoadLibraryExA("c:\\zxc\\bar.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR)
```

If `c:\abc\foo.dll` is not loaded in process, then `c:\zxc\foo.dll` gets properly loaded and `c:\zxc\bar.dll` links to it.
But if `c:\abc\foo.dll` is loaded, then `c:\\zxc\\bar.dll` links to `c:\abc\foo.dll` instead of `c:\zxc\foo.dll` (even if `c:\zxc\foo.dll` is already loaded in the process). This was confirmed with help of "Show loader snaps" checkbox of Global Flags.

How do I work around it?

The `bar.dll` is third party so I cannot implement DELAYLOAD in it.

And I cannot prevent loading `c:\abc\foo.dll` to the process.

I'm thinking of hooking `ntdll!LdrpFindOrMapDll`, but it seems unreliable and I will have to test this thoroughly in all supported Windows versions, so I'm first searching for a simpler workaround.

Comment: There is no bug here. The library function is behaving as designed. If a module is implicitly linked by name only, and a module of that name is already loaded into the process, that module is the one that is linked. That is all by design.

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't change the name of your foo.dll? If you changed the name then all of the problems go away without having to bother with workarounds.

Comment: Theoretically, if you load `c:\zxc\bar.dll` *before* loading `c:\abc\foo.dll` it should work.  Provided you load the latter via an explicit path, that is.  (Or are *both* copies of `bar.dll` implicitly loading the corresponding `foo.dll`?)

Comment: Failing all else, you'd probably be better off splitting the application into two separate processes than using hooking.  You could use COM as the IPC mechanism, that way it shouldn't be *too* difficult to rearchitecture.

Comment: if hook - need hook `RtlDosApplyFileIsolationRedirection_Ustr` which is *exported* but not `ntdll!LdrpFindOrMapDll` - this hook will be already enough reliable

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to make your foo.dll a side-by-side assembly, and reference it in your dll manifest.
This is how, for instance, Common Controls of 5 and 6 versions and Visual Studio different C runtime versions supposed to coexist in the same process.

If this works, don't necessarily need to install your foo.dll to WinSxS folder,  maybe you can do with private assemblies.

If side-by-side assemblies won't work for you, then any hooking solution is complex and risky. 
Think of it: number of calls like GetModuleHandleW(L"foo.dll") supposed to return proper one DLL handle in each context! 
(and side-by-side assemblies do this trick if bar.dll code is compiled with ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED defined)